# Is there a library to use kubernetes configmap as key-value store for persistence?

Tags: python, kubernetes, persistence, key-value, configmap

I am looking for a Python library to use Kubernetes directly as key-value store. I am thinking of sth. as follows:

```py
# initialize a configmap
store = python_keyvalue.init_cm("configmap-name")

# set the value
store.set(key="username",value="blubblub")

# retrieve the value
my_username = store.get(key="username")
```

The produced configmap may look as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  username: blubblub
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap-name
```

It seems like a comfortable way to store some values without much overhead.

Of course Python k8s api is [not that complicated](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/notebooks/create_configmap.ipynb), but still things can get complicated quite fast...
Also spinning up a Redis or using sqllite is an option, but for storing one or two simple values this is quite a huge overhead.

Haven't found anything and googling is quite complicated :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigMap

To read, mount the CM as a volume.

To write the values, keep it simple, use  `kubectl patch cm poc-kv --patch '{"data" : {"test" : "no"}}'` inside the container, with the right serviceAccount + RBAC !